# Delphi 'AND' evaluation with 2 conditions

Tags: delphi

I've had to pick up Delphi for a recent contract piece of work I am doing and one of the things I'd like someone to clarify is the execution of logic in a conditional statement such as an `if`.

I come from a background in C/C++ and in those languages, as soon as an `if` statement is known to fail, the rest of the logic is not executed. For example:

```
if (somefunc() == FALSE && anotherfunc() == TRUE)
```

In the case above, if `somefunc()` returns `TRUE` then `anotherfunc()` is never called.

In Delphi from what I can see so far, this does not hold true. Rather, for

```
if (somefunc() = False and anotherfunc() = True) then
```

then, irrespective of what `somefunc()` returns, `anotherfunc()` will be called.

I've read various Delphi books, and reread some of the conditional chapters and can't find mention of this behaviour anywhere at all. Can anyone point me to somewhere in Delphi or Pascal where this behaviour is stated?

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation - "allows but does not require short-circuiting".

Comment: you don't need to write the boolean state ie `= False` or `= True`. Instead you can use the `not` operator to check if false, by not including `not` in part your if statement works in the opposite way, eg true instead of false.

Comment: According to how you intended your Delphi code to be interpreted, anotherfunc *should* get called when somefunc returns false, yet you say that's a problem.

Comment: Sorry for mentioning, but the example code above are erroroneous. You obviously missed some brackets, so the compiler will try to evaluate "FALSE and anotherfunc()" and will not have a  clue what to do with "somefunc()" and "True". Anyway I see your point and understood your question, only I felt better with this told.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [documentation link is here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Boolean_short-circuit_evaluation_(Delphi_compiler_directive)):

> #### Boolean short-circuit evaluation
>
> | Type | Switch |
> | --- | --- |
> | **Syntax** | {$B+} or {$B-} {$BOOLEVAL ON} or {$BOOLEVAL OFF} |
> | **Default** | {$B-} {$BOOLEVAL OFF} |
> | **Scope** | Local |
>
> The $B directive switches between the two different models of Delphi code generation for the **and** and **or** Boolean operators.
>
> In the {$B+} state, the compiler generates code for complete Boolean expression evaluation.
> This means that every operand of a Boolean expression built from the and and or operators is guaranteed to be evaluated, even when the result of the entire expression is already known.
>
> In the {$B-} state, the compiler generates code for short-circuit Boolean expression evaluation, which means that evaluation stops as soon as the result of the entire expression becomes evident in left to right order of evaluation.

As you can see, the default option is for short-circuit evaluation.

---

Unfortunately you got a little mixed up in your test. Your Delphi code is in fact quite different from the C code.

```c
if (somefunc() == FALSE && anotherfunc() == TRUE)       // C code
```

```pascal
if (somefunc() = False and anotherfunc() = True) then   // Delphi code
```

In Delphi the `and` operator has a [higher precedence](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence) than the equality operator `=`. Which means that your Delphi code is equivalent to:

```pascal
if (somefunc() = (True and anotherfunc()) = True) then
```

But in C and C++, the precedence is the other way around. So `&&` has [lower precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `==`. And so the Delphi and C++ if statements in your question are logically different, irrespective of short-circuit evaluation.

I'm quite sure that you really meant to write your Delphi code like this:

```pascal
if ((somefunc() = False) and (anotherfunc() = True)) then
```

That would give the same logic as your C++ code, and you would have seen the same behaviour due to short circuit evaluation.

Finally, you should never test against `False` and `True` in Delphi. Always write the code like this:

```pascal
if not somefunc() and anotherfunc() then
```

Comment: +1 for your last statement alone, I wish I could do another for explaining the underlying problem.

Comment: I switch between Delphi and VS a lot and this always gets me...I'm either adding brackets in C# when they're not needed or forgetting them in Delphi, then promptly giving myself a slap in the face for doing so.

Comment: @J... Yes, I always struggle with this too. I always end up with extra parens in my C# code because I can never remember the operator precedence.

Comment: Great answer. If you think about it, the fact that `somebool and anotherbool` is a valid boolean statement, but `somebool and somevalue = something` isn't kind of forces you to add parentheses around boolean evaluations.

Comment: @nrjohnstone does this help at all?

Comment: AWESOME... Thanks guys, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for... fantastic, what a great community :-) .. THat explanation on the bracketing was perfect, and apologies for my example being incorrect in the begining

Comment: Dave you expand a bit on why you shouldn't test against False and True in Delphi? If the function somefunc() returns a boolean why should I not test for True or False in Delphi?

Comment: @nrjohnstone Well, `if` requires an expression that evaluates to a `Boolean`. And if you have a function that returns a `Boolean` then that is already an expression that evaluates to a `Boolean`. It's clearly superfluous to test against `True` or `False`. Doing so leads you into bracket hell as you have discovered. You are probably coming from a background of older versions of C that do not include a true boolean type. Delphi is different.

Comment: @David Heffernan - yes definitely bracket hell. Thanks for taking the time David, you've really helped me understand this.. And yes, my background is lots of (too much) C90

Comment: I always thought that putting extra brackets (for better understanding and to avoid wrongly guessing operator precedence) in the code is not really an error. If you use a vertical tabulator to separate condition groups, it won't even cause the lack of code readability. Am I wrong? Should I use only the exactly necessary number of brackets? Does this "bracket hell" exists?

Comment: @mg30rg It's the testing against `True` and `False` that is the problem. That then forces you to use parens. Bracket hell is probably over-stating the matter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I totally agree in that case, I would never test against "TRUE"/"FALSE", but I tough it is an example case.

Answer (score 5):

If your function `anotherfunc()` gets called on this code

```
if (somefunc() = False and anotherfunc() = True) then
```

then you have set the `BOOLEVAL ON`

As David pointed out the compiler first evaluate `False and anotherfunc()`

In `BOOLEVAL OFF` mode the compiler knows, that `False and AnyBoolState` will result in `False` and therefore `anotherfunc()` is not called (in fact it will never be called).

As a simple test on that I extended the jachaguate program to show your expression

```
program AndEvaluation;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

function FalseFunc( const AName : string ) : Boolean;
begin
  Write( AName, '(False)', '-' );
  Result := False;
end;

function TrueFunc( const AName : string ) : Boolean;
begin
  Write( AName, '(True)', '-' );
  Result := True;
end;

begin
  try

    // (somefunc() = False and anotherfunc() = True)
    //
    // in this testcase translated to:
    //
    // somefunc()    => FalseFunc( 'First' )
    // False         => FalseFunc( 'Second' )
    // anotherfunc() => TrueFunc( 'Third' )
    // True          => TrueFunc( 'Fourth' )

{$B+}
    Writeln( 'BOOLEVAL ON' );
    if ( FalseFunc( 'First' ) = FalseFunc( 'Second' ) and TrueFunc( 'Third' ) = TrueFunc( 'Fourth' ) )
    then
      Writeln( 'True' )
    else
      Writeln( 'False' );
{$B-}
    Writeln( 'BOOLEVAL OFF' );
    if ( FalseFunc( 'First' ) = FalseFunc( 'Second' ) and TrueFunc( 'Third' ) = TrueFunc( 'Fourth' ) )
    then
      Writeln( 'True' )
    else
      Writeln( 'False' );

  except
    on E : Exception do
      Writeln( E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message );
  end;

  ReadLn;

end.
```

And now lets have a look at the result

```
BOOLEVAL ON
Second(False)-Third(True)-First(False)-Fourth(True)-True

BOOLEVAL OFF
First(False)-Second(False)-Fourth(True)-True
```

As the output explains having `BOOLEVAL ON` your `anotherfunc()` will be called **before** `somefunc()` is called.

With `BOOLEVAL OFF` your `anotherfunc()` is **never** called.

If you want to have the same as

```
if (somefunc() == FALSE && anotherfunc() == FALSE)
```

you have to translate it like this

```
if ( somefunc() = False ) and ( anotherfunc() = False ) then
```

or the *better and shorter* way

```
if not somefunc() and not anotherfunc() then
```

or maybe even shorter

```
if not( somefunc() or anotherfunc() ) then
```

But to avoid getting `anotherfunc()` called every time you have to set `BOOLEVAL OFF`

Comment: +1 This, and the presence of "even when somefunc returns False" in the question tells me that the actual code that the asker was running is `if (somefunc() = True and anotherfunc() = True) then`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that would be the only possibility if `BOOLEVAL OFF` is set :o) let's wait for the OP reaction ...

Comment: Realistically it's hard to imagine the the asker has set BOOLEVAL ON.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid not calling a function you can do it this way:

```
  bool_somefunc := (somefunc() = 42);
  bool_anotherfunc := (anotherfunc() = 17);
  if ( (bool_somefunc = False) and (bool_anotherfunc = True) ) then
```

This ensures that every functon is called either short eval
is turned on or off.