# Evaluation order for if statement in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I know the answer for the following function statement:

```
if (TestFunc1()) and (TestFunc2()) then
    DoSomething();
```

This is nicely answered in this question:
[Delphi 'AND' evaluation with 2 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084323/delphi-and-evaluation-with-2-conditions/15086348#15086348)

You could test this easily by debugging or logging, say. But how would you test what the compiler is doing in this example (say ech parameter is defined as a Boolean):

```
if (SomeObj1.bNaughtyGlobal1) and (SomeObj2.bNaughtyGlobal2) then
    DoSomething();
```

Yes, I know the parameters would ideally be hidden behind accessor functions...but is there a clever way to test whether SomeObj2 is being accessed at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "test whether SomeObj2 is being accessed"? What happens when you read SomeObj2.bNaughtyGlobal2 is that it will take the address where SomeObj2 is supposed to be , add the offset where bNaughtyGlobal2  is supposed to be and get that value at that address.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Your own answer a few minutes after this question is a decent answer, thanks.

Comment: What makes you think an attribute of an object is global?

Comment: @Craig: "Global" in the sense that the attribute is defined as public in the class definition for the object(s). Not strictly relevant, though, as the variable could be local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is just the same as for the question that you link to. It doesn't matter whether the expressions that are operands to `and` are function calls or variables. The second operand will be evaluated if:

1. Short circuit evaluation is not enabled, or
2. Short circuit evaluation is enabled and the first operand evaluated true.

The default compiler options have short circuit evaluation enabled, and I don't know of any scenario where it makes sense to change that. So, assuming that you compile with short circuit evaluation enabled, then the second operand is evaluated if and only if the first operand evaluates true.

If you are keen to see this under a debugger try this program with and without short circuit evaluation:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type 
  TMyRecord = record
    foo: Integer;
  end;
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;

var 
  P: PMyRecord = nil;
begin
  if Assigned(P) and (P.foo=1) then 
    Writeln;
end.
```

Without short circuiting, the evaluation of `P.foo` is a runtime error. With short circuit evaluation there is no runtime error.

Indeed this specific example is one of the best reasons why short circuit evaluation should be enabled. Otherwise such code would be excessively verbose.

Comment: Yes, I've got the short-circuit compilation options enabled (Project > Options > Compiler > Complete boolean eval = OFF). I understand that the compilation should be the same, but with functions you can test what the compiler has done easily enough. Curious to know if there is a clever way to prove this with parameters.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the example. Tried both compiler options and it works or fails as expected. I've made a minor edit to make the example even clearer (hope you think so too). The short-circuit compiler option is definitely to be recommended...and now I understand it much better!

Comment: The example requires a few minor tweaks to compile in Delphi7. Needs a semicolon after the record "end". Variable initialisation (n: Integer = 5;) isn't supported. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the semi-colon correction. The variable initialisation is fine. It has to be a global though as per my code. The code in the question is a complete program remember. So P is a global. Paste it into a .dpr file and it's all good.

Comment: Aah yes, P is global. I tested it as a local variable to a function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Set a breakpoint on

```
if (SomeObj1.bNaughtyGlobal1) and (SomeObj2.bNaughtyGlobal2) then
```

now run your program to the breakpoint.
Open the CPU window (view->Debug Windows->CPU)and step through the processor instructions.
There you will see the jump instruction and you will also see that in case SomeObj1.bNaughtyGlobal1 is false that nothing else will be evaluated, not your SomeObj2 object.

Comment: Just tried that and it works! Not too familiar with assembler, but I was able to see the two "cmp" statements, with the second one getting skipped over. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: @AlainD Funny thing is that you will see different machine code if you turn off short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Yes, well spotted. I can see that when short-circuiting is switched off, that the two "cmp" statements will be run before a "jmp" is hit.

Answer (score 1):

Set `SomeObj1.bNaughtyGlobal1 := False` and `SomeObj2 := nil`. If the compiler is misbehaving and evaluating both sides of the `and` expression, then you'll get an access violation as your program attempts to read the `bNaughtyGlobal2` value from a null reference.

Comment: Nice, actually thought of that about 30 minutes after posting the question.